# Spring boot batch project not compile in terminal but works in STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

This is the error I am getting.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project merchentsettlement: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] Configuration.java:[163,76] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method build()
[ERROR] location: class org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilderHelper
[ERROR] Configuration.java:[178,59] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method build()
[ERROR] location: class org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilderHelper
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at least provide more information like your pom and dependencies.

Comment: Maven has seperated classpath for the scopes (like compile, test, ...); Eclipse/STS hasn't. I guess you are using a wrong scope on some dependencies. It would really help if you include your pom.xml in your question.